# Add download delay in scrapy requests

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy, web-crawler, middleware

Actually, I have a scrapy spiders. And i have multiple proxy ips. I want to add delay in proxy usage for a domain that there should 30 seconds of ip rotation for every domain.
But I have a problem that sometimes all the proxy ips are used for that domain in 10 to 15 seconds. in this case i want to delay to requests for that domain for 15 seconds to available the proxy ips. but there are some ips that can be used for some other domain so that ips should be used for that domain.

Problem:

When for one domain there is no ip available then only the request for that domain should be in sleep and all the other requests for another domain should proceed.

please help in this situation how can i apply the sleep for a specific request rather than all the requests. currently all the requests go to sleep.

```
        request_delayed_time = (delay_time - self.get_request_delay_time(domain, required_rank_proxies))
        print(f"Request is waiting for {msg.get('url')} for {request_delayed_time} seconds")
        time.sleep(request_delayed_time)
```